# Get the mass of a plate with density function

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, density-function

> The density at each point of a 1 cm square plate is $16+r^4$ g/cm<sup>2</sup>, where $r$ is the distance in cm from the point to the centre of the plate. What is the mass of the plate?

I know that mass is the double integration of the density function. My problem is that the function of the density is in polar coordinates but the plate is a square. Should I convert the density function into Cartesians? How do I put the limits after the conversion?

Comment: actually, what you do is do the integral from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \pi/4,$ then multiply by 8. It is not so difficult to write the line $x = 1/2$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Cartesian coordinates supposing the square is centered at $0$. You will obtain the integral $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (16+(x^2+y^2)^2)dxdy,$$
which is easy to calculate.

Comment: Just observe I am using $r = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$ and $dMass = (16 + r^4)dxdy$.

Comment: Is it the same when I do the $4\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}16+(x^2+y^2)^2dxdy$

Comment: Yes. The reason is very simple, the function you are integrating is even with respect to $x$ and $y$.